# Palindrome Program Help: LinkedList of Objects that contain Arrays of doubles.

Tags: object, palindrome, listiterator

Hopefully my title explains what I'm trying to do. I have created a LinkedList:

```
private LinkedList<MyVector> list = new LinkedList();
```

I Have then added to the list by using the constructor of a Palindrome class that I created:

```
//creates arrays of doubles inside of MyVector Objects.
public Palindrome(){

    double[] a1 = {3.0, 4.0, 3.0};
    double[] a2 = {3.5, 4.5, 3.5};

    MyVector a = new MyVector(a1);
    MyVector b = new MyVector(a2);
    MyVector c = new MyVector(a1);
    MyVector d = new MyVector(a2);
    MyVector e = new MyVector(a1);
  //adds the MyVector Objects into the LinkedList  
    list.add(a);
    list.add(b);
    list.add(c);
    list.add(d);
    list.add(e);
}
```

I am now creating a method that will compare the pointers of two different List Iterators through the list of "MyVector" objects:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(){

     //iterates through LinkedList From Beginning to End  
     ListIterator<MyVector> itr1 = list.listIterator();

     //iterates through LinkedList from End to Beginning
     ListIterator<MyVector> itr2 = list.listIterator(list.size());


     while (itr1.next() == itr2.previous()){
            return true;
        }

    return false;

}
```

**My problem is that when I create a new Palindrome object in the main method, and then check to see if the List of objects is in fact a palindrome, I always get an output that "the List isn't a palindrome" (When I specifically made the objects in the list to represent a palindrome for my test if you take a look at my Palindrome constructor):**

```
Palindrome pal = new Palindrome();

    if(pal.isPalindrome()){
        System.out.println("It's a palindrome");

    } else {
        System.out.println("It's not a palindrome");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The == operator uses an objects hashcode to compare it to the other and these don't match.
You can see this by using the following bit of code:

```
int hash1 = itr1.next().hashCode();
int hash2 = itr2.previous().hashCode();
```

You'll need to override and use the equals function in your MyVector class for this to work.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    boolean retVal = true;
    if(other instanceof MyVector)
    {
        MyVector otherVector = (MyVector) other;
        if(this.x != otherVector.x)
        {
            retVal = false;
        }
        if(this.y != otherVector.y)
        {
            retVal = false;
        }
        if(this.z != otherVector.z)
        {
            retVal = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        retVal = false;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I now understand why I get the output that I am getting now. Wouldn't the equals method have the perameter of  (ListIterator<MyVector> temp) since I am comparing the two iterators. I am sorry if that doesn't make any sense. I am still a beginner with all of this so I'm having a tough time understanding what the equals method you made me does.

Comment: The next\previous method gives you an object from your list andere not a ListIterator object. The default equals method compares both objects hashcode. The equals function I provided compares the values for the objects and not its hashcode. I added the instanceof operator in order to verify that object is an instace of MyVector before casting it.